# Electron : dialog message box with a form

Tags: javascript, html, electron

It is possible to get an information dialog box with a form or input?
The idea is if we click on btnDialog , it open the dialog box where we can defined a value for value1 or not.

html :

```
<button id="btnDialog">Define value1</button>
```

Renderer :

```
var value1 = 0;
document.getElementById("btnDialog").onclick = function(){
   ipcRenderer.send('opend');
}
ipcRenderer.on('returnd',(event,index)=>{
   if(index==0){
       //value1 = value of input
   }
});
```

Main :

```
ipcMain.on('opend',(event)=>{
    const options = {
        type:'info',
        title: 'Title',
        buttons:['OK','Cancel'],
        message: 'Define value1 <form><input></input></form>'
    };
    dialog.showMessageBox(options,(index)=>{
      event.sender.send('returnd',index);
    });
});
```

I don't see how to get value from form if necessary.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is NO, you cannot extract a form value from a `Dialog MessageBox`.

The MessageBox API is very clear, it only returns the index of the button pressed, even when using an async callback as you have done above.

The proper way to accomplish your goal is to construct a new [Browser Window](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindow) that would contain a proper form and that you can interact with properly.

Additionally, if you want to remove the Chrome from the Window, you can add [Frameless Window Settings](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#frameless-window).

In either case, you would use the normal messaging API to communicate between the main process and the browser window.